# Apache Nutch and Solr integration

Tags: linux, solr, lucene, nutch

I've tried to follow the [nutch tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search) but having a bit of a problem with the schema.xml file.

I was told to the nutch provided schema to my project, essentially this...

```
cp ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema.xml ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/example/solr/conf/
```

I have deployed my solr file in Tomcat and the error I get when I go to the Solr dashboard is

```
collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text": 
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter:
Error loading class 'solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory'
```

Which relates to this element in my solrconfig.xml file (I can comment this out but not sure how important this is yet)

```
<filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
```

I have edited my solrconfig.xml to try and included a range of jar files that come with solr, specifically

```
<lib path="/etc/solr/collection1/libs/dist/solr-core-4.2.1.jar" />
<lib path="/etc/solr/collection1/libs/dist/solr-analysis-extras-4.2.1.jar" />
```

But I don't think they contain the missing class "solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"

Does anyone have idea why this might not be working or if I have missed something?
I'm not a Java developer btw so no doubt it will be something simple :)

**UPDATE**
After finding out that the schema had some old classes being referenced I had another look in the nutch/conf and tt looks like there is a ${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema-solr4.xml file which seems to work.

Not 100% if this is correct but hey...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like `EnglishPorterFilterFactory` is no longer around in 4.x.  See the note in [it's 3.6.0 documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_0/org/apache/solr/analysis/EnglishPorterFilterFactory.html):

```
Deprecated.
  Use SnowballPorterFilterFactory with language="English" instead
```

A lot of Deprecated stuff went away in 4.0.  I'd do what it says, see the [documentation for SnowballPorterFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballPorterFilterFactory.html).

Comment: Also using "${NUTCH_RUNTIME_HOME}/conf/schema-solr4.xml" instead of old config